# Quantum Espresso magnetization per site

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

### Context

I am doing a SCF calculation on Ni-DOBDC (metal-organic framework). I expect the Ni centres to be d8 high spin, so two unpaired electrons. The metal centres are ferromagnetic within a 1D chain but antiferromagnetic between chains. My spin polarised SCF calculation agrees with the ferromagnetic and antiferromagnetic ordering.

However the magnetization on each Nickel centre is greater than I would expect, at about -/+ 1.45 compared to 1.

```
Magnetic moment per site  (integrated on atomic sphere of radius R)
     atom   1 (R=0.032)  charge= 15.5009  magn=  1.4481
     atom   2 (R=0.032)  charge= 15.5011  magn= -1.4480
     atom   3 (R=0.032)  charge= 15.5005  magn= -1.4485
     atom   4 (R=0.032)  charge= 15.5007  magn=  1.4483
     atom   5 (R=0.032)  charge= 15.5007  magn= -1.4483
     atom   6 (R=0.032)  charge= 15.5004  magn=  1.4485
```

I also calculated the Lodwin charges using projwfc.x and get a similar result.

```
 Atom #   1: total charge =  17.5682, s =  2.4098, p =  6.7856, d =  8.3728,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, s =  1.2187,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, p =  3.4012, pz=  1.1357, px=  1.1264, py=  1.1391,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, d =  4.9266, dz2=  0.9916, dxz=  0.9829, dyz=  0.9802, dx2-y2=  0.9860, dxy=  0.9858,
                 spin down    =   8.0218, s =  1.1911,
                 spin down    =   8.0218, p =  3.3845, pz=  1.1348, px=  1.1136, py=  1.1360,
                 spin down    =   8.0218, d =  3.4462, dz2=  0.8585, dxz=  0.5682, dyz=  0.6009, dx2-y2=  0.7357, dxy=  0.6829,
                 polarization =   1.5246, s =  0.0275, p =  0.0167, d =  1.4803,
     Atom #   2: total charge =  17.5685, s =  2.4098, p =  6.7857, d =  8.3730,
                 spin up      =   8.0220, s =  1.1911,
                 spin up      =   8.0220, p =  3.3845, pz=  1.1348, px=  1.1136, py=  1.1360,
                 spin up      =   8.0220, d =  3.4464, dz2=  0.8585, dxz=  0.5682, dyz=  0.6009, dx2-y2=  0.7357, dxy=  0.6830,
                 spin down    =   9.5465, s =  1.2187,
                 spin down    =   9.5465, p =  3.4012, pz=  1.1357, px=  1.1264, py=  1.1391,
                 spin down    =   9.5465, d =  4.9266, dz2=  0.9916, dxz=  0.9829, dyz=  0.9802, dx2-y2=  0.9860, dxy=  0.9858,
                 polarization =  -1.5245, s = -0.0275, p = -0.0167, d = -1.4802,
     Atom #   3: total charge =  17.5679, s =  2.4098, p =  6.7856, d =  8.3724,
                 spin up      =   8.0214, s =  1.1911,
                 spin up      =   8.0214, p =  3.3845, pz=  1.1348, px=  1.1556, py=  1.0940,
                 spin up      =   8.0214, d =  3.4458, dz2=  0.8585, dxz=  0.4438, dyz=  0.7252, dx2-y2=  0.5423, dxy=  0.8760,
                 spin down    =   9.5464, s =  1.2187,
                 spin down    =   9.5464, p =  3.4012, pz=  1.1357, px=  1.1543, py=  1.1112,
                 spin down    =   9.5464, d =  4.9266, dz2=  0.9916, dxz=  0.9812, dyz=  0.9820, dx2-y2=  0.9840, dxy=  0.9878,
                 polarization =  -1.5250, s = -0.0275, p = -0.0167, d = -1.4807,
     Atom #   4: total charge =  17.5681, s =  2.4098, p =  6.7856, d =  8.3727,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, s =  1.2187,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, p =  3.4012, pz=  1.1357, px=  1.1176, py=  1.1479,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, d =  4.9266, dz2=  0.9916, dxz=  0.9806, dyz=  0.9825, dx2-y2=  0.9877, dxy=  0.9841,
                 spin down    =   8.0216, s =  1.1911,
                 spin down    =   8.0216, p =  3.3845, pz=  1.1348, px=  1.1052, py=  1.1444,
                 spin down    =   8.0216, d =  3.4461, dz2=  0.8585, dxz=  0.7415, dyz=  0.4275, dx2-y2=  0.8496, dxy=  0.5689,
                 polarization =   1.5248, s =  0.0275, p =  0.0167, d =  1.4806,
     Atom #   5: total charge =  17.5681, s =  2.4098, p =  6.7856, d =  8.3727,
                 spin up      =   8.0216, s =  1.1911,
                 spin up      =   8.0216, p =  3.3845, pz=  1.1348, px=  1.1052, py=  1.1444,
                 spin up      =   8.0216, d =  3.4461, dz2=  0.8585, dxz=  0.7415, dyz=  0.4275, dx2-y2=  0.8496, dxy=  0.5689,
                 spin down    =   9.5465, s =  1.2187,
                 spin down    =   9.5465, p =  3.4012, pz=  1.1357, px=  1.1176, py=  1.1479,
                 spin down    =   9.5465, d =  4.9266, dz2=  0.9916, dxz=  0.9806, dyz=  0.9826, dx2-y2=  0.9877, dxy=  0.9841,
                 polarization =  -1.5248, s = -0.0275, p = -0.0167, d = -1.4806,
     Atom #   6: total charge =  17.5677, s =  2.4098, p =  6.7856, d =  8.3723,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, s =  1.2187,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, p =  3.4012, pz=  1.1357, px=  1.1543, py=  1.1112,
                 spin up      =   9.5464, d =  4.9266, dz2=  0.9916, dxz=  0.9812, dyz=  0.9820, dx2-y2=  0.9840, dxy=  0.9878,
                 spin down    =   8.0213, s =  1.1911,
                 spin down    =   8.0213, p =  3.3844, pz=  1.1348, px=  1.1556, py=  1.0940,
                 spin down    =   8.0213, d =  3.4457, dz2=  0.8586, dxz=  0.4438, dyz=  0.7251, dx2-y2=  0.5423, dxy=  0.8760,
                 polarization =   1.5251, s =  0.0275, p =  0.0167, d =  1.4808,
```

### Question

Is this difference between expected and calculated magnetization (ie. +/- 1.0 vs +/- 1.45) indicative of a problem? And if so what would be the best way to correct?

**Note:** the structure has not been relaxed (vc-relax), I want to get the starting magnetization conditions correct before expending alot of compute time.

Comment: I think QE uses units of Bohr magneton for spin, so 2 unpaired electrons would give 2, not 1. Your value of 1.45 indicates a small decrease from this idealised picture, which looks perfectly reasonable to me - especially given the crude approximations in population analysis methods.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Please update us! Was Phil's comment helpful?